# java can not intercept SQLException for "invalid operation at cursor position" Error

Tags: java

I have a routine that gets a piece of text from a text field. I use this to search a database for any matches. If one or more matches found it works correctly. However, it no match is found it gets the expected "invalid operation at cursor position" SQLException.

The problem is I want to intercept that exception and produce my own message.  But I can not seem to do it.

The following code fragment is an example of the code and the png is the resulting image of the result!

// Note that code uses different field for query but result is the same!

```
private void btnFnidNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

   getQueryFields();
    String CMD = "SELECT * FROM TREE_DATABASE WHERE LCASE(first_name)   LIKE LCASE('%"+q_first_name+"%')  ";  // q_first_name is query String!

    try {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(CMD);
        rs.next();
        getResultSet();
        setTextFields();
    }
//
// Setting breakpoints next two lines and never get a break!
//

    catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tree.this, err.getMessage());
    }
```

[image: Result of function on screen]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps replace

```
catch (SQLException err) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tree.this, err.getMessage());
}
```

with

```
catch (SQLException err) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tree.this, "Your personal error message here");
}
```

Comment: It still produces same result  -- I tried that option.  As I said I placed breakporints a catch and it never seems to call the catch clause!

Comment: Which button, from the screen shot did you click to receive this message? Is it the "Execute" button?

Comment: Yes - I got the text from the variables returned by getQueryFields and when

Comment: Execute button is pressed it is processed.  I found out that the rs.next() was the problem. If rs does not return a result, rs.next try to step to a cursor location that does not exist. So I bypassed to error.

Comment: But this still does not answer the real problem, WHY DOES JAVA NOT HANDLE THE EXCEPTION IN THE "CATCH" Claus???

Comment: the method name you provided above is called: btnFnidNextActionPerformed.. While you click the "Execute". I suspect the catch is caughed in another method called btnExecuteActionPerformed?

Answer (score 0):

Even if a little late ... It is slightly unclear what `rs` even is; I'd just assume it returns `true` or `false`. While you cannot call `getResultSet()` when already having reached the end of the record-set. For such a singular form, you may want to `LIMIT 1` ...and likely use something alike:

```
if(rs.next()) {
    getResultSet();
    setTextFields();
}
```

Alternatively, in case multiple records are being returned:

```
while(rs.next()) { ... }
```